# RMagick gem works in Passenger perfectly but cant find formats in console or rake task to do same conversion from PDF to JPEG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, passenger, rmagick

I was trying to run a rake task that processes some PDFs into JPEGs. The code works fine in the Passenger environment (as a web server process).

I was getting this error in the console and in the rake task.

```
ArgumentError: unknown format: PDF
```

It looks like rmagick sees the available formats in the Passenger server but not in the rails console. I ran Magick::formats to get a list of available formats and this is what I got in both environments.

When I try to run as a rake task or in the rails console, I get a blank list of formats:

In console:

```
2.5.0 :001 > Magick::formats
 => {}
```

In passenger server:

```
{"3FR"=>" r--", "A"=>"*rw+", "AAI"=>"*rw+", "AI"=>" rw-", "ART"=>"*rw-", "ARW"=>" r--", "AVI"=>" r--", "AVS"=>"*rw+", "B"=>"*rw+", "BGR"=>"*rw+", "BGRA"=>"*rw+", "BMP"=>"*rw-", "BMP2"=>"*-w-", "BMP3"=>"*-w-", "BRF"=>"*-w-", "C"=>"*rw+", "CAL"=>"*rw-", "CALS"=>"*rw-", "CANVAS"=>"*r--", "CAPTION"=>"*r--", "CIN"=>"*rw-", "CIP"=>"*-w-", "CLIP"=>"*-w+", "CMYK"=>"*rw+", "CMYKA"=>"*rw+", "CR2"=>" r--", "CRW"=>" r--", "CUR"=>"*rw-", "CUT"=>"*r--", "DCM"=>"*r--", "DCR"=>" r--", "DCX"=>"*rw+", "DDS"=>"*r--", "DFONT"=>"*r--", "DNG"=>" r--", "DOT"=>" ---", "DPX"=>"*rw-", "EPDF"=>" rw-", "EPI"=>" rw-", "EPS"=>" rw-", "EPS2"=>"*-w-", "EPS3"=>"*-w+", "EPSF"=>" rw-", "EPSI"=>" rw-", "EPT"=>" rw-", "EPT2"=>" rw-", "EPT3"=>" rw+", "ERF"=>" r--", "FAX"=>"*rw+", "FITS"=>"*rw-", "FRACTAL"=>"*r--", "FTS"=>"*rw-", "G"=>"*rw+", "G3"=>"*rw-", "GIF"=>"*rw+", "GIF87"=>"*rw-", "GRADIENT"=>"*r--", "GRAY"=>"*rw+", "GROUP4"=>"*rw-", "HALD"=>"*r--", "HDR"=>"*rw+", "HISTOGRAM"=>"*-w-", "HRZ"=>"*rw-", "HTM"=>"*-w-", "HTML"=>"*-w-", "ICB"=>"*rw-", "ICO"=>"*rw+", "ICON"=>"*rw-", "INFO"=>" -w+", "INLINE"=>"*r--", "IPL"=>"*rw+", "ISOBRL"=>"*-w-", "JNG"=>"*rw-", "JPEG"=>"*rw-", "JPG"=>"*rw-", "K"=>"*rw+", "K25"=>" r--", "KDC"=>" r--", "LABEL"=>"*r--", "M"=>"*rw+", "M2V"=>" rw+", "M4V"=>" rw+", "MAC"=>"*r--", "MAP"=>"*rw-", "MAT"=>" rw+", "MATTE"=>"*-w+", "MEF"=>" r--", "MIFF"=>"*rw+", "MNG"=>"*rw+", "MONO"=>"*rw-", "MOV"=>" rw+", "MP4"=>" rw+", "MPC"=>"*rw+", "MPEG"=>" rw+", "MPG"=>" rw+", "MRW"=>" r--", "MSL"=>"*rw+", "MSVG"=>" rw+", "MTV"=>"*rw+", "MVG"=>"*rw-", "NEF"=>" r--", "NRW"=>" r--", "NULL"=>"*rw-", "O"=>"*rw+", "ORF"=>" r--", "OTB"=>"*rw-", "OTF"=>"*r--", "PAL"=>"*rw-", "PALM"=>"*rw+", "PAM"=>"*rw+", "PATTERN"=>"*r--", "PBM"=>"*rw+", "PCD"=>"*rw-", "PCDS"=>"*rw-", "PCL"=>" rw+", "PCT"=>"*rw-", "PCX"=>"*rw-", "PDB"=>"*rw+", "PDF"=>" rw+", "PDFA"=>" rw+", "PEF"=>" r--", "PES"=>"*r--", "PFA"=>"*r--", "PFB"=>"*r--", "PFM"=>"*rw+", "PGM"=>"*rw+", "PICON"=>"*rw-", "PICT"=>"*rw-", "PIX"=>"*r--", "PJPEG"=>"*rw-", "PLASMA"=>"*r--", "PNG"=>"*rw-", "PNG24"=>"*rw-", "PNG32"=>"*rw-", "PNG8"=>"*rw-", "PNM"=>"*rw+", "PPM"=>"*rw+", "PREVIEW"=>"*-w-", "PS"=>" rw+", "PS2"=>"*-w+", "PS3"=>"*-w+", "PSB"=>"*rw+", "PSD"=>"*rw+", "PTIF"=>"*rw+", "PWP"=>"*r--", "R"=>"*rw+", "RADIAL-GRADIENT"=>"*r--", "RAF"=>" r--", "RAS"=>"*rw+", "RGB"=>"*rw+", "RGBA"=>"*rw+", "RGBO"=>"*rw+", "RLA"=>"*r--", "RLE"=>"*r--", "SCR"=>"*r--", "SCT"=>"*r--", "SFW"=>"*r--", "SGI"=>"*rw+", "SHTML"=>"*-w-", "SR2"=>" r--", "SRF"=>" r--", "STEGANO"=>"*r--", "SUN"=>"*rw+", "SVG"=>" rw+", "SVGZ"=>" rw+", "TEXT"=>"*rw+", "TGA"=>"*rw-", "THUMBNAIL"=>"*-w+", "TIFF"=>"*rw+", "TIFF64"=>"*rw-", "TILE"=>"*r--", "TIM"=>"*r--", "TTC"=>"*r--", "TTF"=>"*r--", "TXT"=>"*rw+", "UBRL"=>"*-w-", "UIL"=>"*-w-", "UYVY"=>"*rw-", "VDA"=>"*rw-", "VICAR"=>"*rw-", "VID"=>"*rw+", "VIFF"=>"*rw+", "VST"=>"*rw-", "WBMP"=>"*rw-", "WMF"=>"*r--", "WMV"=>" rw+", "WMZ"=>"*r--", "WPG"=>"*r--", "X3F"=>" r--", "XBM"=>"*rw-", "XC"=>"*r--", "XCF"=>"*r--", "XPM"=>"*rw-", "XPS"=>" r--", "XV"=>"*rw+", "Y"=>"*rw+", "YCbCr"=>"*rw+", "YCbCrA"=>"*rw+", "YUV"=>"*rw-"}
```

I have verified that I am running the same version of RMagick in both console and passenger:

Console:

```
2.5.0 :005 >  Magick::Long_version
 => "This is RMagick 2.16.0 ($Date: 2009/12/20 02:33:33 $) Copyright (C) 2009 by Timothy P. Hunter\nBuilt with ImageMagick 6.7.5-10 2016-11-16 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org\nBuilt for ruby 2.5.1\nWeb page: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org\nEmail: rmagick@rubyforge.org\n"
```

Passenger:

```
This is RMagick 2.16.0 ($Date: 2009/12/20 02:33:33 $) Copyright (C) 2009 by Timothy P. Hunter Built with ImageMagick 6.7.5-10 2016-11-16 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org Built for ruby 2.5.1 Web page: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org Email: rmagick@rubyforge.org
```

I'm thinking that it may be a path issue between passenger and my local environment.

I have tested this on 2 server instances I am running with similar configurations with the same result.

#### System Configuration

- ImageMagick version:  6.9.8-3 Q16
- RMagick version: Latest Version 4.2.2
- Ruby version:  ruby 2.5.1p57
- Environment: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to set a few environment variables:

```
export MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH=/.../ImageMagick-6.9.8/config:/opt/bitnami/common/
export MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH=/.../ImageMagick-6.9.8/modules-Q16/coders
export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/bitnami/common
```

On my Dev box (my mac) these were set automatically when I installed ImageMagick.